# Attempting to connect SSH to a machine using a domain

Tags: ssh, login, domain

I am having trouble (only recently) logging into a machine at work.

I have always entered my credentials like `username@domain.local`. But it doesn't seem to work anymore...

I noticed that after typing the username, and before typing the password it says: **`username@domain.local@machine.domain.local's password:`**

Is this normal that the remote machine is "tagged" on to the end of my username? Or is it the root of my login problem?

Comment: Is `username@domain.local` an Active Directory account? Did the server previously prompt `username@domain.local's password`? Did you previously have to log on to that server as `username` rather than `username@domain.local`?

Comment: Yes it is an ad account. Yes and no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can replicate this to a Debian-based system joined to an Active Directory domain, and I get a successful login with the correct password:

```
ssh -l roaima@domain.local remotehost
roaima@domain.local@remotehost's password:
```

My guess would be that the remote server has been recently updated from using `winbindd` to `sssd` for its AD authentication layer.

Why you are getting a permission denied error is not something that can be easily diagnosed without access to the remote host in question.

I would start by looking at the authentication log files on the server. In a Debian-based environment that would be `/var/log/auth.log`, the files corresponding to your client in `/var/log/samba`, and files under `/var/log/sssd`.

Be aware that the domain usage changed from `winbindd` to `sssd`, so any "allowed groups" in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` may need adjusting.

---

Update for early 2022. Even if you're using `sssd` you still need `winbind`. On my servers I abandoned `sssd` about a year ago (because I didn't need it to manage login sessions) and reverted to using `winbind` to talk directly to AD.

Answer (score 0):

Probably is a resolver problem
Check /etc/resolv.conf on both sides

```
yourdomain.yourextension
```

or

```
yoursubdomain.yourdomain.yourextension
```

can be OK

```
yourdomain.yourextension.yourdomain.yourextension
```

not.

Check also the hostname and try to resolve using

```
dig hostname.domain
```